# Detecting Facebook User without explicit login

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I saw a site: http://earnlikes.com . Even if I don't give any facebook application any permission for this site, this site can track which pages I have liked on it. Anyone knows how is that possible? I have tried clearing my cache and changing my IP address. They are not tracking my likes using cookies or IP addresses.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: They probably use a Facebook widget iframe that loads a page/script from Facebook to show likes.

Comment: Could you figure out how they track the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems that they are using the "*page*" you are submitting as an ID to know how many likes you clicked...etc
2. They are using [`edge.create`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event to capture the likes and update the session AND (guessing here) the database count
3. Try submitting your FB page from a different computer (or browser) you'll see the points earned

And now the most important point: "***While they are claiming that it's totally legal to use their service, I really doubt that this is true***"
And if you really want to promote your page

- provide a cool content and
- start a website(blog maybe) on the same topic
- use Facebook ads

I've reported the website anyway, to check what Facebook will say about it.

Comment: I have figured out the edge.create part already. I am gonna try another PC. I am concerned about how they're keeping track of me.

Comment: @Abu Ashraf Masnun: as I said, as long as you are submitting the same facebook page you'll be treated as the *same* user.